# Show Text box to capture comment on button click in Modern SharePoint List View Formatting

Tags: list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am building a card using View Formatting to allow user take the Approve or Reject Action.

[image]

I am able to successfully update the status on button click using setAction attribute but, what I want is, if user select Reject then I need to capture the comments.

Is it possible to show the text box and capture comments?

Also open for the other alternatives as well. Goal is to achieve this approval mechanism with list formatting.